# How can I get user response from adaptive card using Adaptive Cards Action.Submit action from MS Teams channel using Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How can I get user response from the adaptive card using Adaptive Cards Action.Submit action from MS Teams channel using Microsoft Bot Framework?

Here is my sample Adaptive Card with two button Yes and No. Once the user will click on any button, I need to capture the response in the bot application in the backend implemented using Microsoft Bot Framework 4.

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
{
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "text": "Does this information help you?"
},
{
  "type": "ActionSet",
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Execute",
      "title": "Yes",
      "verb": "personalDetailsFormSubmit",
      "id": "surveyReplyYes",
      "userIds": "" ,
      "data":{
        "key1": true,
        "key2":"okay"
      },
       "fallback": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Yes"
      }  
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Execute",
      "title": "No",
      "verb": "personalDetailsFormSubmit",
      "id": "surveyReplyNo",
      "userIds": "" ,
       "data":{
        "key1": false,
        "key2":"np"
      },
       "fallback": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "No"
      }  
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every channel has some additional requirement to achieve this kind of requirement obviously MS Teams Channels Adaptive card required special property with the name "msteams" to the object in an object submit action's data property. As per your adaptive card, it only contains **'data'** property so change a little bit and try it out.

**Example:**

```
{
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Click me for messageBack",
"data": {
"msteams": {
    "type": "messageBack",
    "displayText": "I clicked this button",
    "text": "text to bots",
    "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
},
"extraData": {}
}
}
```

**Reference:** [Adaptive Cards in Teams](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your bot is a service waiting to be called by the user. When the user sends a regular text message, that will come in to your bot as a "MessageActivity" event. However, if they click a button in an Adaptive Card, that will come as an "InvokeActivity" event, so you can hook into that and check if the user clicked one of your buttons, and respond appropriately. Here's [an example of a bot doing that](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-teams-catering/csharp/Catering/Bots/CateringBot.cs) based on one of [it's cards](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-teams-catering/csharp/Catering/Resources/DrinkOptions.json). See in particular `OnMessageActivityAsync` vs `OnInvokeActivityAsync` (C# only - see below for Node).

Here's another [very detailed blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) on working with this, covering both DotNet and Node, from the Microsoft Bot Framework team. That post is a bit old, so it doesn't cover what you're using in your sample, which is quite new - [Universal Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/overview?tabs=mobile). It's just a slightly newer way of specifying the json for the Action.

This is totally *optional*, but there's also a way to make the card buttons behave a little differently. For instance, when the user clicks a button you can make it appear as if the user -typed- that text into the bot. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json) for more on that.